# Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7056 after 45000 ms by manual create session

Tags: firefox, selenium, grid, webdriver

I've start hub and node on a same machine and I open http://localhost:5555/wd/hub/static/resource/hub.html on firefox browser. I create firefox session but it alert me "Unable to create new session.".

This is my log.

```
11:18:02.374 INFO - Executing: [new session: Capabilities [{browserName=firefox}]])
11:18:02.386 INFO - Creating a new session for Capabilities [{browserName=firefox}]
org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7056 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
Error: no display specified
Error: no display specified

    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:118)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:246)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:114)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:193)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:186)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:104)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:532)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverProvider.callConstructor(DefaultDriverProvider.java:59)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverProvider.newInstance(DefaultDriverProvider.java:53)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverFactory.newInstance(DefaultDriverFactory.java:54)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$BrowserCreator.call(DefaultSession.java:214)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$BrowserCreator.call(DefaultSession.java:1)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$1.run(DefaultSession.java:168)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
11:18:47.912 WARN - Exception thrown
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Build info: version: '2.45.0', revision: '5017cb8', time: '2015-02-26 23:59:50'
System info: host: 'pdc-server', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'i386', os.version: '3.2.0-23-generic-pae', java.version: '1.6.0_24'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:252)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:111)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession.execute(DefaultSession.java:175)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession.<init>(DefaultSession.java:111)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession.createSession(DefaultSession.java:88)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverSessions.newSession(DefaultDriverSessions.java:109)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.NewSession.handle(NewSession.java:57)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.NewSession.handle(NewSession.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.rest.ResultConfig.handle(ResultConfig.java:110)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.JsonHttpCommandHandler.handleRequest(JsonHttpCommandHandler.java:172)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DriverServlet.handleRequest(DriverServlet.java:201)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DriverServlet.doPost(DriverServlet.java:163)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DriverServlet.service(DriverServlet.java:129)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:428)
    at org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.dispatch(ServletHandler.java:680)
    at org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:571)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpContext.handle(HttpContext.java:1526)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpContext.handle(HttpContext.java:1479)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpServer.service(HttpServer.java:920)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpConnection.service(HttpConnection.java:820)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpConnection.handleNext(HttpConnection.java:986)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:837)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.SocketListener.handleConnection(SocketListener.java:243)
    at org.openqa.jetty.util.ThreadedServer.handle(ThreadedServer.java:358)
    at org.openqa.jetty.util.ThreadPool$PoolThread.run(ThreadPool.java:537)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Build info: version: '2.45.0', revision: '5017cb8', time: '2015-02-26 23:59:50'
System info: host: 'pdc-server', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'i386', os.version: '3.2.0-23-generic-pae', java.version: '1.6.0_24'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverProvider.callConstructor(DefaultDriverProvider.java:69)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverProvider.newInstance(DefaultDriverProvider.java:53)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverFactory.newInstance(DefaultDriverFactory.java:54)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$BrowserCreator.call(DefaultSession.java:214)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$BrowserCreator.call(DefaultSession.java:1)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$1.run(DefaultSession.java:168)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:532)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverProvider.callConstructor(DefaultDriverProvider.java:59)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Failed to connect to binary FirefoxBinary(/usr/bin/firefox) on port 7056; process output follows: 
Error: no display specified
Error: no display specified

Build info: version: '2.45.0', revision: '5017cb8', time: '2015-02-26 23:59:50'
System info: host: 'pdc-server', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'i386', os.version: '3.2.0-23-generic-pae', java.version: '1.6.0_24'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:130)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:246)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:114)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:193)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:186)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:104)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7056 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
Error: no display specified
Error: no display specified

    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:118)
    ... 20 more
11:18:47.920 WARN - Exception: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7056 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
Error: no display specified
Error: no display specified
```

I've use firefox 10 with selenium-server-standalone-2.45.0.jar.
What should I do?

Comment: Firefox 10 ? this sounds pretty old, can you try to upgrade to a more recent  version

Comment: do you run from command line or you are already on desktop?

Comment: Try with a new firefox version, if it doesn't work then in that case try to open the Grid and Hub link on browser and see whether are you able to open the links in browser or not.

Comment: sure, I opened it on browser and tried to create session on it. 
well I'll try a newer version of firefox soon.

Comment: well, I've change to version 24.0 but still not work.
But when I test on VM with the firefox 24.0 and selenium-server-standalone-2.45.0.jar it can work with no problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I resolved this problem already.
In my log it said "Error: no display specified"
because DISPLAY variable had no value,
so when I start hub and node I use the following command instead.

```
export DISPLAY=":1" && java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.45.0.jar -role hub
```

and

```
export DISPLAY=":1" && java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.45.0.jar -role node -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register
```